# solve a parabolic PDE backwards in time

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, parabolic-pde

I am trying to solve the following equations:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    -\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}&=\Delta u+Cu+Z, (x,t)\in\Omega_T\\
     \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&=0, x\in \partial \Omega_T   \\
     u(T,x)&=0, \forall x\in\Omega.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where I employ the BTCS(backward in time and central space) method. This kind of problem is usually not well-posed so I make a time transformation such that $s=T-t$ which makes it as an initial problem
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial s}&=\Delta u+Cu+Z, (x,s)\in\Omega_T\\
     \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&=0, x\in \partial \Omega_T   \\
     u(0,x)&=0, \forall x\in\Omega.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
However, I still encountered the solution blows up(goes to huge numbers)... is there any reference to such problems?

Comment: Are you sure about the initial condition? This way one solution is $u(x,s) = 0$ and even an explicit method for time advance will stay in the (correct) zero solution.

Comment: I forgot to add a constant source term.

Comment: Did you satisfy the CFL condition? If $\delta t$ and $\delta x$ are the grid parameters, you shloud have something  like $\delta t \leq \alpha \delta x^2$.

Comment: yes, I chose the CFL constant to be 0.02 which should be enough.